# Visual Studio fails debugging JavaScript in IE9 - says "The correct version of pdm.dll is not registered"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I encountered this problem after installing IE10, finding it did not work well on my Windows 7 system, and uninstalling it.  Now, back to IE9, VS2010 could not attach to the process and reported the error.  I followed the instructions to repair the VS2010 installation and did the regsvr32 on pdm.dll.  Still does not work.  Uninstalled IE9, and reinstalled it. Still no luck.

**Here's the solution:**
The key is that the message says the incorrect version of pdm.dll is not registered.  Apparently the IE10 install provided a new pdm.dll and the re-install of IE9 did not replace it.  I found an older version on another system, copied it to the C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug folder, registered it, and now VS2010 debugging works again.

Comment: The solution for me required copying more `.dlls` from that directory than just `pdm.dll`. Also make sure to register them.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've struggled with this issue for months. Justin is right: the solution requires copying and registering more dlls. But this is great!

Answer (score 2):

**Here's the solution** unfortunately did not help me.

My solution:
- Remove IE 10
- Cotrol panel - Programs and Features - VS 2012 - change - repair.(I've selected download components from internet)

Answer (score 0):

See the "Here's the solution" comment.  I had the answer when I posted it, but wanted to share it and avoid more wasted hours by others.

Comment: Please post "Here's the solution" as an answer and mark it as such.

Comment: This really isn't a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

We solved a similar issue registering again all the dll's in

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug
```

For first one remember to use:

```
%systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe
```

and for 2nd ones (32 bit):

```
%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe
```

If that is not enough go to VS debug menu and go to Options and configuration > Just-In-Time, uncheck all the options there (Administered, Native, Script) and click OK

Go to some place and check again those options and click OK again.