# Visual Studio 2010 cannot debug javascript after uninstalling IE10

Tags: visual-studio

My dev machine got the automatic update from IE9 to IE10. The latter is broken on our development web site, so I uninstalled the IE 10 "update" to revert to IE9.

Visual Studio 2010 will no longer attach its debugger to the browser. I can either debug in IE9 developer mode, or attempt to launch a new instance of VS'10 to debug (but that doesn't work either.)

What can I do to restore the link between VS'10 and IE'09?

EDIT:
I get the dialog titled "Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger".

"An unhandled exception ('Script Breakpoint') occurred in iexplore.exe [4824]

Possible debuggers:
New Instances of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
....
"
I cannot attach to the already running instance of VS.

Comment: "Visual Studio 2010 will no longer attach its debugger to the browser." it shows some error?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled VS'10 including SP1. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I've long since moved on from this development machine. This question should probably be closed or deleted since I can't confirm the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to re-install the .net library.

[.Net Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21)

Answer (score 0):

This post suggests a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343268/visual-studio-fails-debugging-javascript-in-ie9-says-the-correct-version-of-p):

> Here's the solution: The key is that the message says the incorrect
>   version of pdm.dll is not registered. Apparently the IE10 install
>   provided a new pdm.dll and the re-install of IE9 did not replace it. I
>   found an older version on another system, copied it to the C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug folder, registered it,
>   and now VS2010 debugging works again.

However, I'm not yet sure how to download the file called for in this solution.

Comment: From reading that, it looks like you can get it from a PC that has IE9, rather than downloading it.