# Visual Studio fails debugging JavaScript after IE downgrade

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I had IE11 on my workstation and was able to debug my JavaScript functions. However, my users are using IE8 and are experiencing an issue that I am unable to reproduce with IE11.  So I downgraded my browser from IE11 to IE8 for troubleshooting this and am unable to debug the JavaScript functions now. Here's the error:

```
The correct version of pdm.dll is not registered
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343268/visual-studio-fails-debugging-javascript-in-ie9-says-the-correct-version-of-p), I need to get the correct version of the `VS7Debug` folder. Where can I get this folder for IE8?

P.S. I have tried VS 2010, 2012 & 2008 for debugging and all of them complain the same. I have a 64-bit OS (Windows Server 2008 R2).